# Pushing items in a list in Python

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say there's a list of `[0, 3, 14, 0]` and i want to 'push' the items of that list to the right corner. So the list will become `[0, 0, 3, 14]`. So basically the items with value > 0 will ignore the 0s and replace its position. The number could be anything (except 0) so sorting won't do it. Couple of examples:

1. `[0, 4, 0, 4]` => `[0, 0, 4, 4]`
2. `[1, 0, 2, 2]` => `[0, 1, 2, 2]`
3. `[13, 0, 0, 6]` => `[0, 0, 13, 6]`

Is there an efficient solution to this? I have been racking my brain for hours and i've found nothing near a solution.

Comment: Do you mean `sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k!=0)` ?

Comment: what the heck dude. i-i wow... *clap* *clap*. Thank you!

Comment: how does that work tho

Comment: @Lucifer1002 Sorting the list requires O(nlogn) operations. This problem can be solved in O(n). The proposed solutions are less "beautiful" but probably faster than using `sorted`

Comment: Value that is not equal to zero is `True`, and `False` < `True` so every `True` value will go to the right. And Python's sort is stable, so it won't change positions between the same values (booleans in this case).

Comment: @Lucifer1002 And here I was thinking that you were actually interested in an "efficient solution to this" but it seems like any solution would have sufficed. In that case, randomly shuffling the list and checking whether it is a valid state repeatedly is a valid solution since efficiency is not a concern and as number of shuffles approach infinity the probability of getting a valid state approaches 1.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco he probably just wants someone to give him any answer, and the "efficient solution" bit is just to make it more likely that someone will answer :/

Comment: @JulianChan that's really not fair, O(NlogN) isn't that much worse than linear, and *effectively* python's `sorted` implementation is very fast, especially for lists that contain long runs of already sorted subsequences. It's a timsort, so a very clever adaptive mergesort. I'd be willing to be that for most use-cases it will beat out a hand-written linear solution in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is worse than linear though. If he isn't that interested in efficiency, he shouldn't be asking about efficiency. And besides while I agree with your assessment that `sorted` implementation is very fast, I doubt that the OP as a beginner would know that. He probably would've just went with whatever worked, even if it was O(n!).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient solution:

```
dst_lst = [n for n in lst if n <= 0] + [n for n in lst if n > 0]
```

This will traverse the original list twice and create two temporary and one final list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an efficient solution that is not inplace, and faster than sorting, you can do this:

```
lst = [0,1,2,0]
helper = [0 for i in len(lst)]
counter = 0
for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
    if lst[i]:
        helper[len(lst)-1-counter] = lst[i]
        counter += 1
print(helper)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps!

Here we are using Python pre-defined data type `queue`

```
>>> import queue
>>> t = queue.deque()
>>> for each in [0, 4, 0, 4]:
...     if each <= 0: t.appendleft(each)
...     else: t.append(each)
...
>>> t
deque([0, 0, 4, 4])
```